# How to create on behalf of flow to generate a access token for Bot authentication from Web Chat?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

Webchat application is a app service. It uses Azure AD authentication (openid) to authenticate the user.
Code to generate access token for Webchat:

```
options.ClientId = this._azureOptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = $"{this._authProvider.Authority}v2.0";
            options.CallbackPath = this._azureOptions.CallbackPath;
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;                
            var allScopes = $"{this._azureOptions.Scopes} {this._azureOptions.GraphScopes}".Split(new[] { ' ' });
            foreach (var scope in allScopes)
            {
                options.Scope.Add(scope);
            }



OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                        var identifier = context.Principal.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.ObjectIdentifierType).Value;
                        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
                        var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                        var result = await this._authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code);
                        context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);

                        this._logger.LogInformation("OnAuthorizationCodeReceived");
                    },
```

Bot application which is registered in azure also accesses graph api. But it asks for sign-in prompt again if user asks a specific question to bot which needs to fetch information from graph API. Once user clicks on sign-in then new token is genrated.

> I want to avoid this oauth prompt and want to generate AAD token for
> BOT from webchat itself

I am trying to do it by assertion but code is failing with error **Signature of token is invalid**

Code to generate token for bot from webchat :

```
authContext = await this.CreateAuthenticationContext(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                "api://appid of bot service principal",
                new ClientCredential(client id of webchat, ClientSecret of webchat),
                new UserAssertion(token generated for webchat, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result.AccessToken;
```

I am not able to generate a token. Following exception occurs:

> AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason – The key
> was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client:

Exception Details :

```
AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., Thumbprint of key used by client: '86E37DE48BCF7DE86ADF81B30436751971A2AE73', Found key 'Start=06/07/2020 00:00:00, End=06/07/2025 00:00:00']
Trace ID: ecd8178f-4fe6-4292-9cc0-3cfe99987a00
Correlation ID: 6f44db8c-ef54-430e-a4e5-2518f191e23f
Timestamp: 2020-07-30 22:19:27Z
```

Comment: You are not able to do that in this way, oauth will not allow you for mixing client id and secrets between applications. "The key was not found" error is because you did not create that access token before in the bot oauth application provider, but in the webchat.

Comment: @LukeDuda any solution you suggest?

Comment: Hi @SagarK,Pllease share details in your issue such as correlation id.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity Sure

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity Added details Please check

Comment: Hi @SagarK, Please check your clientsecret and confirm it is matching with the   client secret or tumbnail in azure

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity It is not matching. There are two service principle. One for webchat and another for Bot. I am trying to create access token for bot using access token generated for webchat (assertion object in code) and passing resource as "api/cliendid" of service principle for bot.